# Is it possible read XML files that are linked to within another XML file "all in one go"?

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, linq, asynchronous

I have an XML file stored on a server which contains elements, of which some are refererences to other xml files e.g.

```
<xml>
<item>value</item>
<data>http://www.example.org/item1.xml</data>
<data>http://www.example.org/item2.xml</data>
</xml>
```

Where item1 and item2 are like this for example:

```
<item>
  <id>1</id>
  <name>Item One</name>
</item>
```

I want to be able to read the main XML file (which of course I can do) this is done with an Asyncronous web request to download the XML - would it be possible to read the XML files referenced within the XML file in the same "request" rather than spin up, in this case two more seperate webclient requests to download these, as because these would be asyncronous too and therefore this data would not be available until those requests have completed - for binding to a UI in XAML for instance.

This would result in the main xml file being downloaded and completed and then the two xml files being seperately downloaded too.  Is it possible to read the main xml and the "sub xml" files all in one go?

I can only use Async webrequests as this is a platform limitation of Silverlight and I cannot change the data as it is distibuted between many XML files to save server storage and is in a provided format, can the main and sub XML files be downloaded and parsed in one request, using LINQ / XElement / Silverlight supported features - I cannot use XPath as this would not be supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unless the fetching on the server side is done by ASP.NET or anything 'active'. Differently put, if you're fetching the XML as a static file using HTTP, then of course nothing will work except what you already know - parse the XML on reception, then fire off two more requests.

If you're serving your Silverlight app from an ASP.NET capable server, you can always build a small aspx (even better ashx) which will fetch all of the XML files, merge them and respond with only one XML.

Comment: The source files are provided by a third party in this format so I would like to be able to do this but only have a client app. Guess the merging has to be server side - I thought this would be the case.

Comment: Yes, there's no way to do this client-side only. Out of curiosity, why would you prefer to have it client-side only?

Comment: The files are third-party hosted too and happen to be in this format to be consumed by a silverlight app - I don't have the facility to have the data on servers myself.

Comment: Read all files out and store them into a relational database?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to establish a `relation` between a generic `item.xml` and lots of `subitem.xml` files. (right ?)

Then you should rather use a relational database instead of trying to connect xml files.
Or put all together in one file, as long as it's not getting to big.
Everything else is waste of your time. :)

Comment: If it were up to me I'd do this but the data is in this format - flat-file XML with links to other XML files within them - just thought I could chain them into one Async Request - more wishful thinking to solve it on my part, as I cannot change the format the data is stored in.